# htaccess parameter

Tags: .htaccess, url-parameters

I have the following rewrite. The last one is par ID, but I want it variable, has to be ID or Quantity, is that possible?

now:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1&item=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
```

must be:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1&item=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1&item=$2&quantity=$3 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can perform what you want to do purely in `.htaccess`

You probably are looking for:

```
 RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1&item=$2&id=$3&quantity=$3 [NC,L]
```

And in `index.php`, you can determine whether $3 is an ID or a quantity.